# passing struct.unpack() data to c-function as a pointer

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a tuple of n-bytes from `struct.unpack()`. I want to pass this data as a pointer to one of the c-functions. I'm trying the following:

```
byref(c_void_p(tuple_data))
```

But this results in the following error:

> TypeError: cannot be converted to pointer

The following works, but the data is not what is expected, when I parse the data in the c-function.

```
 byref(c_char_p(str(tuple_data))
```

I wanted to know if I'm missing anything basic here.

Comment: What format of the data does your C function expect? There is no direct equivalent of a tuple in C-land, so you'll have to do some sort of conversion. Furthermore, `c_void_p` is not used this way, it creates literal pointer from a number (so `c_void_p(0)` is a null pointer).

Comment: .....are you maybe trying to pass the same structure that you unpacked with `struct.unpack`? That's probably already in the format that you need. Most likely you won't even need `byref` in that case, just use `c_char_p(packed_data)`, which is already a pointer.

Comment: That's not the way of doing it. Usually when using *ctypes* you will need to mimic the *C* stuff in *Python* (e.g. types definitions, function signatures, ...).

Comment: @matjcik my function expects pointer to raw binary data of certain bytes. Yes, i have struct.unpack() data. It is of type tuple. c_char_p(packed_data) returns the following error.

      TypeError: string or integer address expected instead of tuple instance